# The resulting array was too large in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the following formula, and I'm getting: The resulting array was too large.

Any ideas? I have over 20k rows.

UPDATE: If I can accomplish this formula with a script, that would be great. Thanks!

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTRANGE(Links!B2,"uno!A:AF");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B3,"dos!A:AF");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B4,"tres!A:AF");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B5,"cuatro!A:AF");IMPORTRANGE(Links!B6,"cinco!A:AF")}))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the sample sheet you are working on? That way the community will have a better view of the data you are trying to pull with IMPORTRANGE, remember to always  include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I can't share it because I have sensitive data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by script this way

```
function test() {
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id2')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('uno')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id2')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('dos')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id3')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('tres')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id4')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('cuatro')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id5')
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('cinco')
  var values = sh.getRange('A1:AF'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
};
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: try the script (replace id1, id2, id3, id4 and id5 by your files'id)

Comment: I knew the script was going to be succesfull!! Thank you so much! It worked!! Any advice in case it brokes again? The data that I'm handling, will increase during a normal week